# Kafka connect -Debezium- Oracle JDBC Sink connector error consuming debezium(oracle) CDC event

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, oracle-cdc

I have below images running in docker.

quay.io/debezium/connect:2.0

quay.io/debezium/kafka:2.0

quay.io/debezium/zookeeper:2.0

container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:latest

**debezium-source-connector config**

```
  "name": "customers-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topic.prefix": "server1",
    "database.hostname": "dbz_oracle21",
    "database.port": "1521",
    "database.user": "c##dbzuser",
    "database.password": "dbz",
    "database.dbname": "ORCLCDB",
    "database.pdb.name": "ORCLPDB1",
    "database.server.name": "server1",
    "table.include.list": "C##DBZUSER.CUSTOMERS",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.customers",
    "internal.key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "internal.value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "internal.key.converter.schemas.enable":false,
        "internal.value.converter.schemas.enable":false,
    "transforms": "route",
    "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.route.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
    "transforms.route.replacement": "$3"
```

**Oracle-JDBC-Sink-Connector Config:**

```
    "name": "jdbc-sink-2",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "CUSTOMERS",
        "table.name.format": "kafka_customers",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbz_oracle21:1521/orclpdb1",
        "connection.user": "c##sinkuser",
        "connection.password": "sinkpw",
        "auto.create":true,
        "auto.evolve":true,
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "pk.fields": "id",
        "insert.mode":"insert",
        "pk.mode": "record_key"
    }
```

I can see the CDC events getting published to kafka topic : "customers".

```
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"ID"}],"optional":false,"name":"server1.C__DBZUSER.CUSTOMERS.Key"},"payload":{"ID":1011}}       {"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"ID"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"NAME"}],"optional":true,"name":"server1.C__DBZUSER.CUSTOMERS.Value","field":"before"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"ID"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"NAME"}],"optional":true,"name":"server1.C__DBZUSER.CUSTOMERS.Value","field":"after"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"version"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"connector"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"name"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"ts_ms"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"name":"io.debezium.data.Enum","version":1,"parameters":{"allowed":"true,last,false,incremental"},"default":"false","field":"snapshot"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"db"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"sequence"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"schema"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"table"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"txId"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"scn"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"commit_scn"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"lcr_position"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"rs_id"},{"type":"int32","optional":true,"field":"ssn"},{"type":"int32","optional":true,"field":"redo_thread"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"user_name"}],"optional":false,"name":"io.debezium.connector.oracle.Source","field":"source"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"op"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"ts_ms"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"total_order"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"data_collection_order"}],"optional":true,"name":"event.block","version":1,"field":"transaction"}],"optional":false,"name":"server1.C__DBZUSER.CUSTOMERS.Envelope","version":1},"payload":{"before":{"ID":1011,"NAME":"r 3"},"after":{"ID":1011,"NAME":"233"},"source":{"version":"2.0.1.Final","connector":"oracle","name":"server1","ts_ms":1674978001000,"snapshot":"false","db":"ORCLPDB1","sequence":null,"schema":"C##DBZUSER","table":"CUSTOMERS","txId":"0a001b007a020000","scn":"3252353","commit_scn":"3252452","lcr_position":null,"rs_id":null,"ssn":0,"redo_thread":1,"user_name":"C##DBZUSER"},"op":"u","ts_ms":1674978030086,"transaction":null}}
```

When I try to sink these CDC event from topic name "customers" with sink connector config, I see error message in connector log -

```
tition CUSTOMERS-0   [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator]
2023-01-29 14:57:13,174 INFO   ||  [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-jdbc-sink-2-0, groupId=connect-jdbc-sink-2] Resetting offset for partition CUSTOMERS-0 to position FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[172.17.0.3:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}}.   [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState]
2023-01-29 14:57:13,181 INFO   ||  Attempting to open connection #1 to Oracle   [io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider]
2023-01-29 14:57:13,222 INFO   ||  JdbcDbWriter Connected   [io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter]
2023-01-29 14:57:13,263 ERROR  ||  WorkerSinkTask{id=jdbc-sink-2-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: PK mode for table 'kafka_customers' is RECORD_KEY with configured PK fields [id], but record key schema does not contain field: id   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: PK mode for table 'kafka_customers' is RECORD_KEY with configured PK fields [id], but record key schema does not contain field: id
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.metadata.FieldsMetadata.extractRecordKeyPk(FieldsMetadata.java:208)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.metadata.FieldsMetadata.extract(FieldsMetadata.java:97)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.metadata.FieldsMetadata.extract(FieldsMetadata.java:63)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:114)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:66)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:74)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:581)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:333)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:234)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:203)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:244)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2023-01-29 14:57:13,263 ERROR  ||  WorkerSinkTask{id=jdbc-sink-2-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:611)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:333)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:234)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:203)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:244)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: PK mode for table 'kafka_customers' is RECORD_KEY with configured PK fields [id], but record key schema does not contain field: id
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.metadata.FieldsMetadata.extractRecordKeyPk(FieldsMetadata.java:208)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.metadata.FieldsMetadata.extract(FieldsMetadata.java:97)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.metadata.FieldsMetadata.extract(FieldsMetadata.java:63)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:114)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:66)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:74)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:581)
        ... 10 more
2023-01-29 14:57:13,263 INFO   ||  Stopping task   [io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask]
```

Comment: As you have in the sinc config `"pk.fields": "id",` and in the payload `{"ID":1011}`; `record key schema does not contain field: id` -> this could be a *case problem*.

Comment: Thanks @MarmiteBomber. Not sure how I missed it. This helped me to fix it :)

Comment: Posted it as an answer;) @jaadev

Comment: I added  "delete.enabled":true, to my sink connector config.But delete is not happening from sink connector table.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle is know as a *case insensitive* system, so `select id from tab` works even if the column name is `ID`.

But most application *quote* the column name, so the cofiguration

```
"pk.fields": "id"
```

will lead to something like `select "id" from tab`

which will trigger the error `record key schema does not contain field: id`

Fix the *case*.